# Set classifier for maven artifacts Promoting Builds in Jfrog Artifactory using Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I am trying to promote snapshot jar to release.I need to differentiate promoted jars using maven classfier name.  Is there a way to change version or set classifier while promoting a build in jfog Artifactory?

```
def promotionConfig = [
// Mandatory parameters
'targetRepo'         : 'libs-prod-ready-local',

// Optional parameters

// The build name and build number to promote. If not specified, the Jenkins job's build name and build number are used
'buildName'          : buildInfo.name,
'buildNumber'        : buildInfo.number,
// Comment and Status to be displayed in the Build History tab in Artifactory
'comment'            : 'this is the promotion comment',
'status'             : 'Released',
// Specifies the source repository for build artifacts.
'sourceRepo'         : 'libs-staging-local',
// Indicates whether to promote the build dependencies, in addition to the artifacts. False by default
'includeDependencies': true,
// Indicates whether to copy the files. Move is the default
'copy'               : true,
// Indicates whether to fail the promotion process in case of failing to move or copy one of the files. False by default.
'failFast'           : true
]

// Promote build
server.promote promotionConfig
```

Answer (score 1):

The  pipeline [promotion](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Scripted+Pipeline+Syntax#ScriptedPipelineSyntax-PromotingBuildsinArtifactory) DSL (or the Artifactory build promotion API) does not support changing the artifact's version or classifier as part of the promotion.
What you can is leverage the [release management](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Scripted+Pipeline+Syntax#ScriptedPipelineSyntax-MavenReleaseManagementwithArtifactory) capability in order to have a release build which changes the artifact version.
When using Maven, the release management capability allows you to change the artifact version, for example from a snapshot to a release version, and apply this change to the .pom files as well.
The [Maven Release Management with Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Scripted+Pipeline+Syntax#ScriptedPipelineSyntax-MavenReleaseManagementwithArtifactory) section of the Jenkins Artifactory plugin contains the required syntax and explanation for performing this transformation.